# Google Apps Marketplace - changing scopes

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have an existing app that's registered in the Google Apps Marketplace. We now need to retire one scope that it uses and add another.

We are trying to decide whether we:

- delete and add in one go; or
- add the new one and then retire the other one at a later date.

I appreciate that adding a scope will require an admin to grant access to the App again, but can anybody confirm the impact of removing a scope? Does that also cause the admin to grant access again?

In short: does *any* change require admin intervention, or just scope *additions*?

Answer (score 1):

Old scopes (that were requested and approved by user and you delete them from your marketplace SDK configuration page) that were approved by user at certain time will still remain approved for the user until he revokes the data access and re-grant it again.

New scopes as said by KENdi will not be approved until user approves (re-grant) access again, though all old scopes still will be available for you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can add a new scope with the Google Apps Marketplace without deleting the old or unused scope. But take note note that your customer will still need to grant the access for the new scope/s in the ADMIN console.

Based on this [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/faq#how_can_i_update_my_marketplace_listing), to update OAuth scopes, enable new extensions, and other application settings, go to Google API Console. Click APIs, then go to the Configuration tab under Google Apps Marketplace SDK.

For more information, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/authorizing).