# How to change scopes in Marketplace SDK?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have changed the required scopes of our application in the marketplace SDK but on install the app is still requesting the old scopes.
What are we missing?

See also:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72450194

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855437/google-apps-marketplace-changing-scopes), old scopes (that were requested and approved by user and you delete them from your marketplace SDK configuration page) that were approved by user at certain time will still remain approved for the user until he revokes the data access and re-grant it again. This may be the reason why the old scopes are available. Also from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/faq#how_can_i_update_my_marketplace_listing):

> To update OAuth scopes, enable new extensions, and other application settings, go to [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Click APIs, then go to the Configuration tab under G Suite Marketplace SDK.